# Как правильно переделать строку под php?

Tags: php, zend-framework-3

Раньше у меня во вьюхе для вывода изображения использовался такой код

```
<img src="<?= $this->url('application', ['action'=>'file'], 
                            ['query'=>['name'=>$foto], 'thumbnail'=>true]); ?>" alt="" class="d-block w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
```

Теперь я переношу эту часть кода в помощник видов. По идее должно получится что-то вроде

```
$result .= '<img src="'.('application', ['action'=>'file'],
                            ['query'=>['name'=>$escapeHtml($foto)],  'thumbnail'=>true]).'" alt="" class="d-block w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">';
```

Но в помощнике видов нет метода

```
$this->url
```

и я не могу сообразить как правильно написать эту строку.

Answer (score 0):

Передайте `url` в помощник параметром, и подставляйте его в результат:

```
class SomeHelper
{
  public static function myImg($url) {
    ...
    $result .= '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="" class="d-block w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">';
    ...
  }
}
```

Затем во вьюхе вызывайте, например так:

```
$actual_url = $this->url('application', ['action'=>'file'], ['query'=>['name'=>$foto], 'thumbnail'=>true]);
echo SomeHelper->myImg($actual_url);
```

Comment: Во вьюхе у меня вызывается как раз таки помощник. Но принцип понятен, осталось только в ZF3 найти откуда берется этот метод url.